# code that cause a framework crashed, but when reproduced in a single file, it worked

Tags: c

I have a question regarding this code. I write this code in my framework, and it caused the framework crashed. But when I rewrite this code below in a single file, but it works just fine. I was just wondering, is the code below is correct for memory allocation and freeing it?  (especially for the part of msg->context_var.type = f;)
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
  int value;
  int price;
  int old;
} type_t;


typedef struct {
  type_t            *type;  
} context_t;


typedef struct {
  context_t context_var; 
} send_request;



void send_Message(send_request *msg)
{   

type_t *f = 0;
f = malloc(sizeof(f));
msg->context_var.type = f;
msg->context_var.type->price = 1;
msg->context_var.type->value = 100;
msg->context_var.type->old =120;


printf("value of %d/n", msg->context_var.type->price);
free(f);
}

int main()
{   

    send_request *msg = 0;
    msg = (send_request *) malloc(sizeof(send_request));

    send_Message(msg);
    free(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's wrong.

```
f = malloc(sizeof(f)); /* Wrong */
f = malloc(sizeof(*f)); /* Better ? */
```

`sizeof(f)` will give you the size of a pointer on your machine; `sizeof(*f)` will give you the size of *the object pointed to*.

**EDIT** As requested by @Perception

When you allocate less than you need you're eliciting [**Undefined Behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen (even the desired behavior) and it all depends on the platform, the environment (the moon phase, etc).

```
msg->context_var.type->value = 100; /* Writes beyond what's allocated. */
```

So, depending on the memory layout of the "framework" this might simply overwrite some memory and "work", or it could crash. Frankly I prefer when it crashes straight away.

Comment: Another way might be to combine the declaration and assignment, and pass sizeof(type_t) to malloc.

Comment: @Martin Törnwall I like it but sadly I have to avoid it when using non-c99 compilers (like cl).

Comment: @Martin Törnwall , what do you mean with combining declaration and assignment? Sorry I do not get it..

Comment: @cnicutar - could you expand your answer to include why it 'appears' to work, then crashes in his framework. Re: access to unallocated memory segments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate an instance of `context_t` on the heap, and then `msg->context_var.type` gets the value of the resulting pointer `f`.

Since `msg` is a pointer parameter to the `send_Message` function, no reliable assumptions can be made about what is done with `msg` and its contents after your function exists. As such, when you go on to free the memory pointed to by `f`, you leave a dangling pointer in `msg->context_var.type`.

If the memory it points to is accessed after send_Message exists, there's a fair chance that you corrupt something vital (or read something crazy, like a pointer to 0xdeadbeef), as it might contain something completely different now.

Comment: ... but the *actual* problem is probably that described by cnicutar above. I facepalm myself for missing that. :)

Comment: i think the same at first like you. then you mean I should also write free(msg->context_var.type) ? I tried free(f) and free(msg->context_var.type) and the framework showed a complete crash :D ..

Answer (score 0):

Not only are you allocating wrong size (see cnicutar's answer)-- If you are attaching f to message that is passed by the framework, you probably don't want to free it before the function returns.  You'll need to free it later, though-- probably through some other facility provided by the framework?